# Не могу правильно обработать ошибки Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, исключения, try-catch

Пишу некое API, есть такой код

```
try {
    $data = json_decode($_POST['json']);
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT into " . $table . " (`" . implode('`,`', $data->fields) . "`) VALUES ('" . implode("','", $data->values) . "')")->execute();
    return [
        'error' => null,
        'data' => Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID(),
        'result' => 1
    ];
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Но исключение не срабатывает. Если вставка вызывает ошибку - она просто вываливается. А мне надо, что бы я мог ее отловить и передать назад в ответе, что то типа такого

```
return [
        'error' => $e->getMessage(),
        'data' => null,
        'result' => 0
    ];
```

Помогите понять, что тут не так

Comment: Добрый день. Вы хотите показать страницу с ошибкой или как Вы хотите показать ошибку?

Comment: я хочу получить текст ошибки так - $e->getMessage(), а сейчас получаю стандартный вывод

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под стандартным?

Comment: вот например - http://joxi.ru/LmGMQRxtR6neJA

Comment: Проверил Ваш код, он показывает ошибку так, как Вы хотите на моём localhost, то есть, "Error: Undefined index: json ". Замените только echo на return. Если хотите показать страницу ошибки, то тут, я думаю, надо будет другой подход использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот Ваш код с разными вариантами вывода ошибки.

Первые два выведут ошибку в debug панели, "ошибка" и "предупреждение" соответственно.
Третий вариант - страницу ошибки, ну и последний просто сообщение на белый экран.

```
try {
$data = json_decode($_POST['json']);
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT into users (`" . implode('`,`', $data->fields) . "`) VALUES ('" . implode("','", $data->values) . "')")->execute();
  return [
    'error' => null,
    'data' => Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID(),
    'result' => 1
  ];
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
  //Yii::error($e->getMessage());
  //Yii::warning($e->getMessage());
  //throw new \yii\web\HttpException(500, $e->getMessage());
  return  'Error: ' .  $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```